# Week Start Is Sunday But sum(values) From Mon-Sun

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

I have a requirement where start of the week is sunday. but all the values should be captured from Monday-sunday and not sunday-Saturday

For Example below is my source

```
 SummedValue    WeekStart   CreatedDate
 1349           2/25/2018   2/25/2018
 982            2/25/2018   2/26/2018
 60             2/25/2018   2/27/2018
 196            2/25/2018   2/28/2018
 200            2/25/2018   3/1/2018
 30             2/25/2018   3/2/2018
 500            2/25/2018   3/3/2018
 500            3/4/2018    3/4/2018
```

I would like to have values summed up like below

```
  SummedValue   WeekStart   CreatedDate
     982            2/25/2018   2/26/2018
     60             2/25/2018   2/27/2018
     196            2/25/2018   2/28/2018
     200            2/25/2018   3/1/2018
     30             2/25/2018   3/2/2018
     500            2/25/2018   3/3/2018
     500            2/25/2018   3/4/2018
```

Basically, for the week 2/25/2018, summedvalue should be calculated from 2/26/2018-3/4/2018 and should be 2468
I tried with various combinations

```
DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0, getdate()), 0),DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, getdate()), CAST(getdate()AS date)) etc
```

Can we do this in sql?

Answer (score 0):

Does this get what you want?

```
SELECT WeekStart, SUM(SummedValue) AS Sum
FROM table_name
WHERE WeekStart <> CreatedDate
GROUP BY WeekStart
```

Comment: If I do this, I get summedvalue=3317. created date would be from 2/25/2018-3/3/2018. How ever I want created date from 2/26/2018-3/4/2018 but weekstart till pointing to 2/25/2018.

Comment: I see. Does adding `WHERE WeekStart <> CreatedDate` fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
SELECT 
    WeekStart, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(dd,WeekStart, CreatedDate) BETWEEN 1 and 7 
        THEN SummedValue 
        ELSE 0 END)
FROM 
    yourtable
GROUP BY 
    WeekStart
```

Comment: hi Tyson, This will do right just for this week. the value for 2/25/2018 should be included in the previous week as well. with This calculation the value for 2/25/2018 just goes away and not included anywhere.